# How to attach error in error list Angular template forms

Tags: angular

How to use validator in Angular template forms.
I created emailcomponent in Angular.

```
export class EcEmailComponent implements OnInit, Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {

    if (!this.required) {
      return null;
    }

    const value = this.value;

    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(value)) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return { invalidEmail: true }
    }
  }
}
```

the HTML file for it

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="email"
           #txtBoxEmail="ngModel"
           [(ngModel)]="value"
           [required]="required">

    <div *ngIf="txtBoxEmail.errors">
      <div class="row alert alert-danger alert-div">
        <div *ngIf="txtBoxEmail.errors?.['invalidEmail']">
          <span>
            Please enter valid email
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to show `Please enter valid email`. How to attach `invalidEmail` error to errors array?

Comment: And how are you registering this email validator?

Answer (score 0):

Angular reactive form gives such Validators inbuilt. And you can create custom validators easily.

Email Validator is inbuilt in reactive form. Which is best for your use case.

See the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2hktk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)